# How to create sliders

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a website with Visual Studio 2010.
I want to use a slider that when the user uses it will change the value of a label.
But i cannot find any type of slider on Toolbox.
Visual studio doesn't provide a so standard tool?

Comment: The slider is not a standard control on web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the [asp.net Ajax Control Toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) that is an add on with more controls

and here is a slider example:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Slider/Slider.aspx